# Get percentage in a dataframe with ddply function

Tags: r, plyr, percentage

I have this dataframe `mydf`

```
structure(list(Driver = c("Crop agriculture", "Crop agriculture", 
"Infrastructure", "Infrastructure", "Mining", "Mining", "Mixed Agriculture", 
"Mixed Agriculture", "Other land use", "Other land use", "Pasture", 
"Pasture", "Tree crops", "Tree crops", "Water", "Water"), Period = c("1990-2000", 
"1990-2005", "1990-2000", "1990-2005", "1990-2000", "1990-2005", 
"1990-2000", "1990-2005", "1990-2000", "1990-2005", "1990-2000", 
"1990-2005", "1990-2000", "1990-2005", "1990-2000", "1990-2005"
), Total = c(120328.157829121, 301821.02190182, 12829.2774726025, 
10727.4383383233, 1087.58971425679, 639.851573022215, 27213.5917382956, 
19832.3424927037, 72326.7471322223, 64524.3243532213, 1064383.44273723, 
1347648.2335736, 7814.32273630087, 7672.0730281537, 20332.6943805768, 
17504.7712037337), n = c("n = 1669", "n = 783", "n = 298", "n = 151", 
"n = 20", "n = 7", "n = 1355", "n = 925", "n = 1623", "n = 851", 
"n = 10986", "n = 6039", "n = 316", "n = 211", "n = 466", "n = 244"
)), .Names = c("Driver", "Period", "Total", "n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

The idea is to get the percentage of each driver for the period. I have tried the ddply function and get this line code.

```
Percentage<- ddply(mydf, c("Driver", "Period"), summarise,
                   percent= ((Total/sum(Total))*100))
```

Howver, I only get 100% values for all the cells. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your call, when you do `sum(Total)` you are using the total value of the **group**, which when used with `Total/sum(Total)` simply produces 1 for this data/grouping. You could calculate the total sum from the entire data set by using `df$Total` in the `sum()` call. With `ddply` this would be

```
ddply(df, .(Driver, Period), summarise, Pct = Total/sum(df$Total) * 100)
```

And here's the `dplyr` equivalent

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Driver, Period) %>% summarise(Pct = Total/sum(df$Total) * 100)
```